# How to prove that $\frac{\pi}{2}=\left[1, 1, \tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{4},\ldots\right]$?

Tags: continued-fractions

I don't know how to prove the generalized continued fraction
$\pi/2=[1;1/1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...]=1+\cfrac{1}{1/1+\cfrac{1}{1/2+\cfrac{1}{1/3+\cfrac{1}{1/4+\ddots}}}}$

It appears on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Generalized_continued_fraction) without proof, it contains the terms of the harmonic series but it seems not to be very well known.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The reference seems to be from https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly/american-mathematical-monthly-december-2008 ... Pickett and Coleman, "Another Continued Fraction for $\pi$."  But the full text appears to require a subscription.

Comment: From that article it is noted that the convergents of this continued fraction $a_n = [1; 1,1/2,\ldots,1/n]$ gives the partial product of the Wallis product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product (1, 2/1, 4/3, 16/9,...). Perhaps you can try to prove that (issue of convergence aside...).

Comment: @mjqxxxx thanks, I don't have access either so I will try to see what I can do but it really help to have a reference.

Comment: @bonsoon thanks, yes that is the part I need to understand the most, Yourong 'DZR' Zang answer mentions Van Vleck's theorem to this part so I'm trying to read the wikipedia page to get the idea of how it goes.

Comment: Added the given reference and another one to the wikipedia page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The article shows that as the harmonic series $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, one can apply Van Vleck's theorem to show that the $2n$th and $(2n+1)$th convergents of the continued fraction $[1; 1, 1/2, 1/3,\dots]$ both exist and converge to the same limit.

The author transforms $[1;1,1/2,1/3,\dots]$ into the form
$$1+\frac{1\cdot1}{1+\frac{1\cdot2}{1+\frac{2\cdot3}{1+\dots}}}$$
by multiplying the numberator and the denominator of the $n$th fraction by $n$. Let $f_n$ be the numerator or the denominator of the $n$th (even) convergent then $f_n$ satisfies the relation
$$f_n=(2n^2-4n+3)f_{n-2}-(n-1)(n-2)^2(n-3)f_{n-4}$$
By direct substitutions, one can show that $A_n$ and $B_n$ where $A_n=\prod_{k\text{ even}}^nk^2$ and $B_n=(n+1)\prod_{k\text{ odd}}^{n-1}k^2$ satisfy the relation for even $n$s. The fraction $\frac{A_n}{B_n}$ has a limit known as the Wallis product. Since for odd $n$s the $n$th convergent converges to the same limit as previously proved, the continued fraction converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

---

I hope this is a clear summary of the article that can save you some time. Sorry for falsely flagging your question.

---

Edit:

**(1)** If you are not familiar with the Van Vleck theorem, it is helpful to study the Seidel-Stern theorem. This theorem states that if $\sum b_n=\infty$ and $b_n$ positive, then $K(1/b_n)$ (the continued fraction) converges. The proof of this theorem can be found in Waadeland and Lorentzen's text *Continued Fractions with Applications*, Chapter 3 Theorem 3. The proof takes advantage of the fact that
$$\frac{A_{2n+1}}{B_{2n+1}}-\frac{A_{2n}}{B_{2n}}=\frac{1}{B_{2n}B_{2n+1}}\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$. This can be seen from the recursive relation
$$B_{n}=b_nB_{n-1}+B_{n-2}$$
Since the $b_n$ are positive, we have $B_{2n}>B_{2n-2}>\cdots>B_0=1$ and $B_{2n+1}>\cdots>B_1=b_1$. Therefore
$$B_{2n}>b_{2n}b_1+B_{2n-1}>\cdots>(b_{2n}+b_{2n-2}+\cdots+b_2)b_1+1$$
and
$$B_{2n+1}>b_{2n+1}+B_{2n-1}>\cdots>b_{2n+1}+b_{2n-1}+\cdots+b_1$$
Since $\sum b_n$ divergese, the denominator goes to infinity with $n$.

Van Vleck's theorem, on the other hand, concerns the convergence of the continued fraction $K(a_n/b_n)$ with complex $a_n, b_n$. It gives a more general criterion for convergence according to the argument of $b_n$ and the divergence of $\sum |b_n|$ (in our case the argument is zero and $|b_n|=b_n$).

**(2)** The recursive relation is in no way magical. Let $f_n$ be **the denominator or the numerator** of the $n$th convergent, we have
$$f_n=b_nf_{n-1}+a_nf_{n-2}$$
$$f_{n-1}=b_{n-1}f_{n-2}+a_{n-1}f_{n-3}$$
$$f_{n-2}=b_{n-2}f_{n-3}+a_{n-2}f_{n-4}$$
like any continued fraction. Then $f_{n-3}=1/b_{n-2}(f_{n-2}-a_{n-2}f_{n-4})$. Plugging the second relation into the first one, one gets
$$f_n=(b_{n}b_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n-1}b_n/b_{n-2})f_{n-2}-a_{n-1}a_{n-2}b_n/b_{n-2}f_{n-4}$$

After the transformation we did, $b_i=1$ for all $i$ and $a_n=n(n-1)$ for $n>1$. Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
f_n
&=(1+n(n-1)+(n-2)(n-1))f_{n-2}-(n-1)(n-2)^2(n-3)f_{n-4}\\
&=(2n^2-4n+3)f_{n-2}-(n-1)(n-2)^2(n-3)f_{n-4}
\end{aligned}$$

---

References:

Lorentzen, L. and Waadeland, H. (1992). Continued fractions with applications. Amsterdam ; London ; New York ; Tokyo: Elsevier Science Publishers B. V.

Pickett, T.J. and Coleman, A. (2008). Another Continued Fraction for π. The American Mathematical Monthly, 115(10), pp.930–933.

‌
‌

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have upvoted but will wait for others answers for now before accepting, I didn't notice the flag but worry not, moderation is as needed as answers so I appreciate both, I have read about the Wallis product before but I'm not really used to continued fractions and I had never heard of the Van Vleck's theorem, the recurrence relation looks very magical so I'm trying to read the wikipedia page of the theorem to get more sense of how it appears.

Comment: Hi @DanielD. I have updated my answer. I have provided a more elementary convergence criterion that does not require any background knowledge of continued fractions (except for the simplest recursive relation). I have copied the proof of the recursive relation which you found magical from the article. I hope the new version would provide you with a more acceptable explanation.

Comment: @DanielD. Also, $f_n$ in the recursion formula is the not the $n$th convergent. Instead, it is the denominator ($B_n$) or the numerator ($A_n$) of the $n$th convergent. In the article, the author denotes by $f$ the $n$th convergent, and uses $f$ for the recursion, so it's pretty confusing.

Comment: Another nice proof of Seidel-Stern can be found in Khinchin's book: Continued Fractions. I say "another" proof, not to suggest that it's different in some essential way from what's sketched here, but simply to provide a reference to another author writing it up.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs thank you very much for your reference I will try to get my hands on it as well as on the other reference, I want to see as many proof as I can even if not that different.

Comment: Yourong'DZR'Zang  thanks for your edit and comments clarifying things I still need to crunch everything more slowly but I think I get it now and I think you have explanined it plenty so I'm accepting your answer but if you or anyone wants to add another answer I will be happy to upvote it too.

Comment: @DanielD. I'm writing up the induction argument as I remember working it out a few years ago. It's probably inferior to this answer here is many ways, but it might be more accessible for some, and I enjoy the exercise of remembering the details. Not sure when I'll actually hit 'post', though, as I'm simultaneously setting up birthday surprises for a brand new 3-year-old :)

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I'm on a bus myself so don't hurry up because I'm about to lose connection anyway the same happened yesterday that is why I upvoted Yourong's answer first and commented later, I'm sure your answer will be acceptable enough and interesting for others readers too so don't doubt that if I could accept more than one I would, happy birthday to your kid!!

Comment: @DanielD., I've taken a couple of looks at it, and what's coming back to me is that it was a messier induction argument than I initially remembered. I was obliged to show, not only the desired claim, but two or three other things that were needed for the induction step. I seem unable to remember them all. If I work it out later, I'll come back to this post. Since I've lost my own proof, thank you for asking this question!

Comment: @GTonyJacobs same to you thanks for your interest in this question and hope you can complete the argument but feel no pressure, the [Khinchin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin's_constant) looks quite fun so I will try to get the book you suggested by him.

Answer (score 5):

**Matrix Representation of Convergents**

One method to compute [the convervgents of continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) uses matrices:
if $[c_0;c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n]=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
\prod_{k=0}^n\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&c_k\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}p_{n-1}&p_n\\q_{n-1}&q_n\end{bmatrix}\tag1
$$
Since $c_0=1$, and for $k\ge1$, $c_k=\frac1k$ we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\prod_{k=1}^n\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&\frac1k\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}p_{n-1}&p_n\\q_{n-1}&q_n\end{bmatrix}\tag2
$$

---

**Closed Form**

We will show by induction that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\prod_{k=1}^{2n}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&\frac1k\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}&\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
\frac{\binom{2n}{n}2n}{4^n}&\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}
\end{bmatrix}\tag3
$$
Note that $(3)$ is true for $n=0$. Assume $(3)$ is true for some $n$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{#C00}{\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}}&\color{#C00}{\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}}\\
\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}2n}{4^n}}&\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\1&\frac1{2n+1}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}&\color{#C00}{\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}}\\
\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}&\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}
\end{bmatrix}\tag4
$$
The left column of the result is easy, the right column top element is
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00}{\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}}\cdot1+\color{#C00}{\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}}\cdot\frac1{2n+1}
&=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\tag{5a}\\
&=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\frac{(2n+2)^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\tag{5b}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}}\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
the right column bottom element is
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}2n}{4^n}}\cdot1+\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}\cdot\frac1{2n+1}
&=\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
We can continue
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{#C00}{\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}}&\color{#C00}{\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}}\\
\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}&\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\1&\frac1{2n+2}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}&\color{#C00}{\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}}\\
\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}&\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}(2n+3)}{4^{n+1}}}
\end{bmatrix}\tag7
$$
The left column of the result is easy, the right column top element is
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00}{\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}}\cdot1+\color{#C00}{\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}}\cdot\frac1{2n+2}
&=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}+\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\frac4{\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)^2}{(n+1)^2}}\tag{8a}\\
&=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}+\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\frac1{2n+1}\tag{8b}\\
&=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\frac1{\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n+2)^2}}\tag{8c}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\frac{4^{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}}\tag{8d}
\end{align}
$$
the right column bottom element is
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}\cdot1+\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}}\cdot\frac1{2n+2}
&=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}{4^n}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+3)}{(2n+2)^2}\tag{9a}\\
&=\color{#090}{\frac{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}(2n+3)}{4^{n+1}}}\tag{9b}
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$ and $(7)$ show that $(3)$ is true for $n+1$.

---

**Estimating the Convergents**

$(1)$ and $(3)$ show that
$$
\frac{p_{2n-1}}{q_{2n-1}}=\frac1{2n}\left(\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\right)^2\tag{10}
$$
$$
\frac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}}=\frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\right)^2\tag{11}
$$
$(10)$ and $(11)$ can be unified as
$$
\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{4^{\lceil n/2\rceil}}{\binom{2\lceil n/2\rceil}{\lceil n/2\rceil}}\right)^2\tag{12}
$$
$(10)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509) says that
$$
\pi\left(n+\tfrac14\right)\le\left(\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\right)^2\le\pi\left(n+\tfrac13\right)\tag{13}
$$
Since $\frac n2\le\lceil n/2\rceil\le\frac{n+1}2$, $(12)$ and $(13)$ show that
$$
\frac\pi2\left(1-\frac1{2n+2}\right)\le\frac{p_n}{q_n}\le\frac\pi2\left(1+\frac2{3n+3}\right)\tag{14}
$$
which, by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), says that
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1;1,\tfrac12,\tfrac13,\dots,\tfrac1n\right]=\frac\pi2}\tag{15}
$$
[image]

---

**Wallis Product**

The [Wallis Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) for $\pi$ is
$$
\frac\pi2=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}\tag{16}
$$
Consider the partial products
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{2k+1}\frac{2k}{2k-1}\tag{17a}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}\left(\frac{2k}{2k-1}\right)^2\tag{17b}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)2k}\right)^2\tag{17c}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\right)^2\tag{17d}
\end{align}
$$
Note the similarity between $(11)$ and $\text{(17d)}$.

Comment: Pretty neat proof! I like how the squeeze theorem shows how useful is to separate odd and even terms, I put some terms on [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2F2%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2F3%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2F4%7D%7D) and try also changing 1/2,1/3 by 1/k+1,1/k+3 for example and other things but I can't see how you realized the fornula for the 2n matrix

Comment: and in the link you use that $(\frac{n+\frac12}{n+1})^2
\le\frac{n+\frac13}{n+\frac43}$ which cross multiplying and resting terms checks out but even though it looks simple I don't have idea either how you realized this was the inequality you needed

Comment: The entries in the $2\times2$ matrix were deduced from looking at the values of $p_n$ and $q_n$ in the [convergents of the continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) and looking at the values of [Wallis' Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: In [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), what one wants is to get a telescoping product, that is where the numerator and denominator differ by $1$, as in $\frac{n+1/3}{n+4/3}$. Since the numerator and denominator in $\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}$ differ by $\frac12$, squaring is indicated. I just needed to figure out that $$\frac{n+1/4}{n+5/4}\le\left(\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}\right)^2\le\frac{n+1/3}{n+4/3}$$

Comment: Thanks for your edit it really helped me understand what I couldn't and I wouldn't have realized either the Wallis product was behind this answer as well if you didn't mentioned it, great visualization too, I surely will come back to let the answers sink more on my head